# How to save scraped web data into multiple csv files

Tags: python, pandas

I'm going to yahoo finance and pulling historical data of the ticker symbol in tickers.
This is being returned in a pandas df.

My question is how would I go about, saving each of the tickers data into their own csv file.

```
tickers = ["MUV2.DE", "DTE.DE", "VNA.DE", "ALV.DE", "BAYN.DE", "EOAN.DE", "RWE.DE", "CON.DE", "HEN3.DE", "BAS.DE", "FME.DE", "WDI.DE", "IFX.DE", "SAP.DE", "BMW.DE", "DPW.DE", "DB1.DE", "DAI.DE", "BEI.DE", "SIE.DE", "ADS.DE", "DBK.DE", "FRE.DE", "HEI.DE", "MRK.DE", "LHA.DE", "VOW3.DE", "1COV.DE", "LIN.DE", "TKA.DE"]

start = datetime.datetime(2012,5,31)
end = datetime.datetime(2020,3,1)

df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(tickers, start=start, end=end)
```

I think I need a for loop to write each to a csv. However, I'm unsure at which stage of the import I write this for loop.

Do I say... for each ticker in tickers go to yahoo get the data and then save it into a csv or do I say go to yahoo get the data and then for each ticker in the df loop through and write to csv?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

```
tickers = ["MUV2.DE","DTE.DE", "VNA.DE", "ALV.DE", "BAYN.DE", "EOAN.DE", "RWE.DE", "CON.DE", "HEN3.DE", "BAS.DE", "FME.DE", "WDI.DE", "IFX.DE", "SAP.DE", "BMW.DE", "DPW.DE", "DB1.DE", "DAI.DE", "BEI.DE", "SIE.DE", "ADS.DE", "DBK.DE", "FRE.DE", "HEI.DE", "MRK.DE", "LHA.DE", "VOW3.DE", "1COV.DE", "LIN.DE", "TKA.DE"]
start = datetime.datetime(2012,5,31)
end = datetime.datetime(2020,3,1)


for ticker in tickers:
    df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start=start, end=end)
    df.to_csv(f"{ticker}.csv")
```